# Cannot identify SMD component

Tags: components, surface-mount

I got this SMT component that looks like resistor or capacitor.
The marking is 1407 15K[image]

I enclosed the image, the size is about 4 mm X 5 mm[image]

Comment: This looks to me like it could be a diode. Does it measure anything on a multimeter?

Comment: Could be a bidirectional TVS diode.